# how to authenticate with svelte and jwt

Tags: jwt, svelte

how to authenticate with svelte and jwt
how to use jwt with svelte
I can't find an example of authentication using only svelte and jwt, no external providers.
is there any example?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? https://dev.to/sirneij/fullstack-jwt-auth-diving-into-sveltekit-login-and-registration-10c2

Comment: JWTs work with Svelte just like any other Javascript framework. If you're referring to SvelteKit, you can use hooks to decode the JWT and place it's parsed value in the session field for the request object.

Comment: @Mooshua is right, JWT token handling is not related to svelte at all, it is more on what you use to make http requests (fetch, axios, etc...). Essentially you need to send the JWT token back to the server in each request, and how to do so depends on the server (cookies, headers, or request body)